# VSCode で参照元への移動のやり方

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vscode

VSCodeでのショートカットについての質問です。

Ruby のコード記述に使用しており、メソッドの定義元への移動は <kbd>F12</kbd> でできましたが、定義元から参照元を一覧で表示して移動したいのですが、調べてもやり方がわかりませんでした。

教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

定義の上で右クリック→「ピーク」→「参照をここに表示」で参照元の表示/移動ができると思います。
ショートカットキーは手元の環境だと<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>になっていました。

メニューが表示されない場合は適切なLanguage Serverがインストールされてないのかもしれません。
[Solargraph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=castwide.solargraph)などを入れてみてください。